# How to implement a NFA or DFA based regexp matching algorithm to find all matches?

Tags: regex, dfa, nfa

The matches can be overlapped.

But if multiple matches are found starting from a same position, pick the short one.

For example, to find regexp parttern **"a.*d"** in a string **"abcabdcd"**, the answer should be {**"abcabd"**, **"abd"**}. And **"abcabdcd"** and **"abdcd"** should not be included.

Comment: Standard RE algorithms are greedy by default, meaning the quantifiers will try to match as much as possible. Thus, `a.*d` would match the whole of `abcabdcd`. Thus, you _need_ a non-greedy match strategy (i.e., match happens the first time you enter an accepting state).

Comment: Actually, the restriction of picking short matches may be loosen or discarded. What I really want is the time efficiency. So we may need some changes in the internal implementation of regexp: NFA or DFA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most RE engines only match an RE once and greedily by default, and standard iteration strategies built around them tend to restart the search after the *end* of the previous match.  To do other than that requires some extra trickery. (This code is Tcl, but you should be able to replicate it in many other languages.)

```tcl
proc matchAllOverlapping {RE string} {
    set matches {}
    set nonGreedyRE "(?:${RE}){1,1}?"
    set idx 0
    while {[regexp -indices -start $idx $nonGreedyRE $string matchRange]} {
        lappend matches [string range $string {*}$matchRange]
        set idx [expr { [lindex $matchRange 0] + 1 }]
    }
    return $matches
}
puts [matchAllOverlapping a.*d abcabdcd]
```

Comment: Alas, this is one of the times when I miss having an option to just do the whole compilation in “non-greedy by default” mode without resorting to trickery with non-greedy wrapping. Haven't got that though…

Comment: Actually, I can't understand the tcl code. Are you still use the standard iteration strategy or anything else? If not, then can you explain me about your idea?

Comment: First, I convert the RE to non-greedy. Then I repeatedly find the first match from the “current” index (initially the start of the string) accumulating the matched substrings and setting the current index to one character _after_ the start of the previously-found match. Once nothing matches, I've got the list of matched substrings I wanted.

Comment: @Rubbish_Oh All algorithms must be at least O(n²) (assuming that RE matching is linear, which it can be for simple cases like yours; forcing to non-greedy helps) but there's no reason to use the horrendous O(n³) approach of hochl's answer.

Comment: Since you "set the current index to one character after the start of the previously-found match", then where are the overlapped matches?

Comment: @Rubbish_Oh The “current” index (i.e., the `idx` variable) is the point at which the RE engine will commence searching. We know that the place where the RE matched the previous time round gives a particular match — we've just found it after all — so we know that the next eligible match point must start _at least_ one character later, and hence that's the place where we start searching from the next time round.

Comment: If you wanted **non**-overlapping matches, Tcl can find those as a one-liner. Many other languages have equally short idioms for that.

Answer (score 0):

This function is rather inefficient, but it solves your problem:

```
def find_shortest_overlapping_matches(pattern, line):
        pat=re.compile(pattern)
        n=len(line)
        ret=[]
        for start in xrange(0, n):
                for end in xrange(start+1, n+1):
                        tmp=line[start:end]
                        mat=pat.match(tmp)
                        if mat is not None:
                                ret.append(tmp)
                                break
        return ret

print find_shortest_overlapping_matches("a.*d", "abcabdcd")
```

Output:

```
['abcabd', 'abd']
```

The ranges assume your pattern contains at least one character and does not match an empty string. Additionally, you should consider using `?` to make your patterns match non-greedily to improve performance and avoid the inner loop.

Comment: Actually, your function is actually the way i've thought about. But what i want is a more efficient algorithm. Thank you all the same.